# when am trying to login my jenkins web UI , it is taking more than 5 minutes

Tags: authentication, jenkins, time

We are using jenkins instance in windows operating system , when am trying to login my jenkins web UI nearly it is taking 5 minutes. how can i improve the web UI login time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you give more context? Did you reproduce this on a single machine, on multiples? Do other apps work OK? Did you check what the process/request is running? etc.

Comment: we have more than 100 users are working on this instance, every one facing same issue and  we are using AD groups .